# Codeigniter load query into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have been trying to figure out how to load the data in a query to an array.

```
$query->row() //only brings back a single row of data when there are more entries in the database.
```

If I just use a foreach loop and echo in the model code below, The data is simply displayed on the screen. It's not in a variable or an array. It is just text on the screen all jammed together.

I had a really hard time trying to find a code example that would show me how to use the

```
$this->db->get_where('table' array('column' => $var);
```

I finally found it but then the example on codeigniters site only echos the query back to the screen.

> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

This is not useful for production.
My controller code is:

```
    public function record(){ 
        /*
         * Here the id is being passed to the record
         * function to retieve the parent and childrens data
         * 
         */
        $getid['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $accld = $getid['id'];

        $data = array();

        $this->load->model('account');
        $account = new Account();
        $account->load($getid['id']);
        $data['account'] = $account;

        $this->load->model('children');
        $children = new Children();
        $children->accld($getid['id']);
        $data['children'] = $children;

        $this->load->view('childeditdisplay', $data );

    }


}
```

My Model code is this:

```
public function accld($id) 
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array('accId' => $id));

    $c_data = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
         $c_data[] = $row ; 
    }
    return $c_data;

    /*
     * Note:
     * I need to figure out how to load to an array to pass back to the 
     * controller to pass to the display
     * I can echo to the screen the results but that is uncontrolled.
     * 
     */
}
```

If I do this:

```
public function accld($id) 
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array('accId' => $id));

    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        echo $row->id ;
        // and all the other fields below here 
    }

}
```

My rows are echoed to the screen. But there is no control. So any help in getting control of my data would be greatly appreciated.

**ANSWER**

This is finally what worked to bring back all the results and not just one row.

```
/**
 * Populate from an array or standard class.
 * @param mixed $row
 */
public function populate($row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}

public function accld($id) {

    $query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array('accId' => $id));

    $this->populate($query->result());
 }
```

Comment: not getting the meaning of want control you want ?? plz print that array and add into the question

Comment: In the code above, my issue is just that the code does not return an array, It prints to the screen the values from the database table. So instead of getting something like Children::__set_state(array(
   'id' => 107) I just get 107 printed to the screen.

Comment: So my question then would be if it is just going to echo out the results from the database how do I control placing them in my view?

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
$query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array('accId' => $id));
$_array = $query->result_array();
```

Do whatever with $_array.

Comment: Try $query->result_array();